# How to configure Mysql with jbpm 6 .1.0 final or jbpm 6.2.0 final in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jbpm

I am using working on jbpm 6.1.0 final, finding difficulty inorder to integrate jbpm 6.1.0 final to mysql database instead of h2.

Can someone please provide me the links of how to do this with coding.

Comment: You're really saying here that you can't type 'jbpm 6' into google and find the jbpm user manual within 5 seconds? A user manual with a section titled 'using your own database' which demonstrates exactly how to setup a MySQL database?

Comment: Hi Gimby,  I knoww jbpm6 doc provide configuration of jbpm6 with mysql. but i am not using jbpm installer neither its eclipse . I have add jbpm plugin into my eclipse. I also know we need to setups xml files. I am strugging to find out what and all  xml files required how to call it through my java code .

Answer (score 0):

It is available in the [User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/jBPMInstaller.html#d0e950)

Comment: Hi Mike,  I knoww jbpm6 doc provide configuration of jbpm6 with mysql. but i am not using jbpm installer neither its eclipse . I have add jbpm plugin into my eclipse. I also know we need to setups xml files. I am strugging to find out what and all  xml files required how to call it through my java code . It would be helpful , if I get some links doing so. Not the mysql configuration with jbpm -installer

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to configure in JBPM engine ? If so, then create a persistence.xml file in Meta-INF folder and point your entitiy manager factory to thet persistence unit. In persistence.xml add hibernate properties that refer to MySQL like Mysql dialect.

Once you do this it will ask for a datasource, that can be taken from server if you are using one, otherwise you can also create a datasource inside persistence.xml. kindly refer to hibernate docs for creating datasource to connect to MySQL.

Hope this helps